# How to take a specific value from an array?

Tags: json, sqlite, ionic-framework, indexeddb

This is how I set the data to the storage

```
this.storage.set('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData) )
```

The data will look like this when saved to the indexedDB

```
[{"user_id":1,"username":"admin"...}]
```

The problem is if I extract the array it only takes 1 character

```
this.storage.get('userData').then((res) => { console.log(res)
  console.log(res[3])
});
```

Like this code above. The `res[3]` will only take the letter `u`

 I wanted to take the name and the value like for example if I call the `res.user_id` it will give me `1` or `res.username` to `admin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did a JSON.stringify... the data is stored now as a string.. so you're taking now the fourth letter of the string "[{\"user... " which is the "u" you get.
Simply make a JSON.parse(res) first... and then you should get the desired results

```
this.storage.get('userData').then((res) => { 
 console.log(res)
 var users =JSON.parse(res) 
 console.log(users[0].username)
 });
```